# How can I create a subfolder [Applescript]

Tags: applescript

The error is with "desktop:_XNB_Extract:"

```
tell application "Finder"
    set x to path to desktop
    make new folder at x with properties {name:"_XNB_Extract"}
    set y to path to "desktop:_XNB_Extract:"
    make new folder at y with properties {name:"Packed"}
end tell
```

Comment: How about `do shell script "mkdir -p $HOME/Desktop/_XNB_Extract/Packed"'`

Comment: Yep, thx for the fast answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Easy vanilla AppleScript solution:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set extractFolder to make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"_XNB_Extract"}
    make new folder at extractFolder with properties {name:"Packed"}
end tell
```

You can even omit `at desktop` because the desktop folder is the *root* folder of the Finder.